# NetworkxError: Failed to relabel nodes : duplicate node label founds. Use relabel=False

Tags: networkx

I tried to read gml file using Networkx with this code : G=nx.read_gml("cond-mat-2003.gml",relabel="true"). But I found this error : networkxerror: failed to relabel nodes : duplicate node label founds. Use relabel=False. I need the labels for further process. How to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does this mean: `relabel="true"`?

Comment: So the `relabel="true"` doesn't appear to be the source of your error, but you mean to use `relabel=True` (error still remains for that file)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error means that more than one node has been given the same label in cond-mat-2003.gml.  There's not much you can do about that.  Perhaps find the node(s) and figure out whether it's a real duplicate or not (it's a big file, so this may not be trivial).  It might be worth emailing the person responsible for the gml file - but he's fairly busy, so I'd first figure out what nodes are causing the problem and call his attention to it then.